# Readers Writers Concurrency Swift Deadlock

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, deadlock

I am trying to fix a deadlock bug that I have in my application. The application has an array where there might be multiple threads requesting data. The array acts as a cache, if the data are there they are returned. If not, the data are not there they are calculated, save to the array and then returned.

**Background Info**

My library, PazProtector, supports synchronous reads and asynchronous writes. When it is writing it is using a barrier to prevent others thread from reading.

The way it is designed it is supposed to be foolproof from deadlocks, as it does not provide direct access to the array. I am also supporting dictionaries and various other object. I am getting the same results on all of them.

To trace the problem I created a framework with a test. When using a small number of iterations the test with successful. When I tried to push it then the test is failing. The same thing happens to the application. It will deadlock, when a lot of data are being updated, which means multiple reads and writes.

**Read Write Lock**

For convenience I have created a read write lock. What it does is pretty simple, it has a queue and it provides read synchronous access and write asynchronous block access.

```
public class PazReadWriteLock {
    public private (set) lazy var queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: self.lockName, attributes: .concurrent)

    public init(lockName: String) {
        self.lockName = lockName
    }

    public convenience init(randomLockName: String) {
        let lockName = PazReadWriteLock.RandomLockName(randomLockName)
        self.init(lockName: lockName)
    }

    public class func RandomLockName(_ prefix: String) -> String {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(10000))
        return "\(prefix).\(random)"
    }

    public private (set) var lockName: String

    public func withReadLock(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.queue.sync {
            closure()
        }
    }

    public func withWriteLock(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.queue.async(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.barrier) {
            closure()
        }
    }
}
```

**PazProtector**

I then created another class called PazProtector, which uses the PazReadWriteLock to protect an item. The class is generic so the item can be any type of object.

```
public class PazProtector<T> {
    private let lock : PazReadWriteLock
    private var item: T

    public init(name: String, item: T) {
        self.lock = PazReadWriteLock(lockName: name)
        self.item = item
    }

    public convenience init(item: T) {
        self.init(name: PazReadWriteLock.RandomLockName("PazProtector"), item: item)
    }

    public func withReadLock(_ block: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        lock.withReadLock() { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            block(strongSelf.item)
        }
    }

    public func withWriteLock(_ block: @escaping (inout T) -> Void) {
        lock.withWriteLock() { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            block(&strongSelf.item)
        }
    }
}
```

To use the PazProtector for an array we initialise:

```
let array = PazProtector<Array<Int>>()
```

To read the array we use the read block

```
        var firstElement: ?
        self.withReadLock { (array) in
            firstElement = array[0]
        }
        print(firstElement)
```

To write on the array we use the write block:

```
        self.withWriteLock { (array) in
            array[0] = 0
        }
```

**PazProtectorArray**

To simplify that I created a PazProtectedArray:

```
public class PazProtectedArray<Element>: PazProtector<Array<Element>> {

    public init(lockName: String) {
        let item = Array<Element>()
        super.init(name: lockName, item: item)
    }

    public subscript(index: Int) -> Element? {
        get {
            var result: Element?
            self.withReadLock { (array) in
                result = array[index]
            }
            return result

        }
        set(object) {
            self.withWriteLock { (array) in
                if let letObject = object {
                    array[index] = letObject
                } else {
                    array.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public func append(_ item: Element) {
        self.withWriteLock { (array) in
            array.append(item)
        }
    }

    public var count: Int {
        var result: Int = 0
        self.withReadLock { (array) in
            result = array.count
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

So now we can almost use it as a normal array without having to worry about block. The only thing we need to take care of is that writing is asynchronous, so when we are out of the block the write operation might still be running. But as it is a barrier block, that should not be a problem is we try to read at the same time as the write operation will block it until write is finished.

**Deadlock**

I hope my assumptions for creating this framework are correct. I have been using it for some time now, without any noticeable issues. Lately I used it on an application that does thousands of reads and writes, when new data come in. I noticed that the application would freeze. When I run it on the debugger I traced the freeze on a read operation that was locked.

**Test**

So I decided to write a test. Initially the test did not push the limits. The iterations were 1000 and the test was passing. Then I decided to push it to 2000 and 5 simultaneous async runs of the same test. This is when I noticed some failures. To prove my case I run the whole thing 50 times, one after the other. This was when I was consistently getting failures.

The fail happens on the waitForExpectations and it does not matter how long you wait 5 or 60 seconds, as if a deadlock occurs it never unlocks. The final version of the test is the following:

```
func testPazProtectedArray() {
    for run in  0...50 {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
        for x in 0...runs {
            let tidalExpectation = self.expectation(description: "\(run):protector\(x)")
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
                // Thread-safe array
                let protectedArray = PazProtectedArray<Int>(randomLockName: "array\(x)")
                var i = self.iterations

                DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: self.iterations) { index in
                    let last = protectedArray.last ?? 0
                    protectedArray.append(last + 1)
                    i -= 1
                    // Final loop
                    guard i <= 0 else { return }
                    //print("a: \(x): \(protectedArray.count) \(protectedArray.last ?? 0)")
                    XCTAssert(protectedArray.count == self.iterations)
                    tidalExpectation.fulfill()
                }

            }
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) in
            if let _ = error {
                XCTFail("Timeout")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Git Repository**

You can find the complete project with the tests on the following repository:

https://github.com/zirinisp/PazProtector.git

I have tried to simplify it and use the array provide on the following example:

https://gist.github.com/basememara/afaae5310a6a6b97bdcdbe4c2fdcd0c6

The above example passes the 1000 iteration test most of the times. I tried it 5-6 times and then I got an error. If I use my test with multiple iterations and runs it will always fail. So it does not have to do with the fact that I have PazProtectedArray -> PazProtector -> PazReadWriteLock

Also on my application the deadlock occurs ussually when there are multiple update happening at the same time. I noticed that adding simple print statement changes the behaviour and make the deadlock happen later or on another point in my code that the PazProtector is used.

**Update 26/06/2017**

This morning I tried replacing my read write lock with the following:

https://github.com/WeltN24/PiedPiper/blob/master/PiedPiper/ReadWriteLock.swift

Unfortunately I got the same results. Most of the run were succeeding, but some of them were failing. Again all failure were because of deadlocks.

Comment: This morning I tried replacing my read write lock with the following:

https://github.com/WeltN24/PiedPiper/blob/master/PiedPiper/ReadWriteLock.swift

Unfortunately I got the same results. Most of the run were succeeding, but some of them were failing. Again all failure were because of deadlocks.

Comment: I just created a new branch called PiedPiperLock (on the PazProtector repository). You can use that if you wish to test using the PiedPiper lock.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this ? I am working on something similar

Comment: @Petar Haven't found a solution yet. Had to refactor a lot of things in my app to make it work. And still, I know that I might get this issue in the future. Let me know if you find something

Comment: @zirinisp can you pls share if you find any solution ?